# White screen after closing (and reopening) flutter modal_bottom_sheet (iOS style)

Tags: flutter, user-interface, modal-dialog

I'm using modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.0 (https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet).
I replaced `MaterialPageRoute<T>` with `MaterialWithModalsPageRoute<T>` and the iOS like transition for the sheet works fine. But after closing and reopening the modal has only a white content. Same the view behind. For both, after scrolling (with that forcing rebuild) the content is available again.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** This was a caching problem of Xcode or the iOS emulator. I encountered this ui bug only on the iOS emulator and after deleting and reinstalling the app it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: Cant create an example. I think There's a bug with using modal_bottom_sheet and flutter_riverpod, but cant reproduce it...